# Why is translation working without transition: all?

Tags: html, css

Why is the animation working without

```
transition: all
```

?

This is the code,

```
.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
 }

.btn:hover {
   transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.btn:active {
   transform: translateY(-1px);
}
```

Both hover and active are translating.  What is wrong?

Comment: share your full code to show us *how it's working* without transition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform does not rely on on transition to do its job. transition's job it so make the transform "animate"

```css
.btn:link,
.btn:visited {}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.transition {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.blue:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.rotate:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<h3>TranslateY</h3>
<button class="btn">
a button with only transform
</button>

<button class="btn transition">
a button with transform and transition
</button>

<h3>Rotate (hover image)</h3>

<img class="rotate" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDWO4.jpg?s=48">
<img class="rotate transition" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDWO4.jpg?s=48">

<h3>Color</h3>

<p class="blue">blue on hover without transition</p>
<p class="blue transition">blue on hover with transition</p>
```

Comment: Exactly, so why is transform working without transition set to all?

Comment: Because transform is independent of transition. You can translate/rotate/skew anything without the need to add a transition. However, if you for examle want to change the duration of the transform, you need to also add a transition